# Python3: How to keep the leading zero when exporting a dataframe to a csv or text file

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, export-to-csv

I am using the following command: (python3)

```
Mydataframe__df.to_csv(string_io, sep=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, header=True, index=False , encoding='utf-8')
df_writer = Mydata_Output.get_writer('/MYFILE_TEST.csv')
df_string = string_io.getvalue()

# save the string as bytes to with the writer
df_writer.write(df_string.encode('utf-8'))

# close the writer connection
df_writer.close()
```

the issue is for the columns with a format like "012345", the leading 0 is removed in the output file even when opening it with Notepad and even when the column format is set as string in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new here too so don't have the street cred here to comment.

You can preserve leading zeros by converting to a string before outputting the data.  Let's say, for example, you want to have eight digits in your data columns, you could use zfill to left pad the string with zeros so it is eight digits long.

```
outvar = str(numvar).zfill(8)
```

Comment: I will try that. i guess i will have to define a format for each of the columns. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I just discovered zfill!  I updated my answer.  If this solved your problem and you could accept it as the answer, it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: that's good to now, thanks - my filed is not always with the same lengh but I found a solution. I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with leading 0 is that when we load the dataframe into panda before to write the csv then panda by default infer its own data type.
The .get_dataframe(infer_with_pandas=False) force to keep the source dataframe.
The issue becomes that when we have nulls in the data (other than string data field) panda does not like it so we need to change everything into string or clean the data before ....
In found the .get_dataframe(infer_with_pandas=False) in one of the publication here. I will try to reference it later.

```
# Read recipe inputs
Mydataframe = dataiku.Dataset("TESTING_for_leading0")
Mydataframe_df = Mydataframe.get_dataframe(infer_with_pandas=False)

Mydataframe_df.to_csv(string_io, sep=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, header=True, index=False , encoding='utf-8')
df_writer = Mydata_Output.get_writer('/MYFILE_TEST.csv')
df_string = string_io.getvalue()

# save the string as bytes to with the writer
df_writer.write(df_string.encode('utf-8'))

# close the writer connection
df_writer.close()
```